# Syntax for Retrieving Value from Nested Style Resource?

Tags: android, android-theme

Since `DrawerLayout` is part of the chrome of an Android activity, a likely background color for the drawer would seem to be the background color of the action bar, so they match. Hence, I'd like to set up the `ListView` that is the drawer contents to have the same background color as the action bar, and I'd like to do that in the layout XML that defines the `ListView`.

And here I get lost in the maze of twisty little passages that is the Android style system...

I know that `?android:attr/` syntax allows you to refer, by reference, to a value defined in the theme being used by the activity (e.g., `?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` as the background for a list item row to work with the "activated" state).

I know that `android:actionBarStyle` is where a theme points to the style to be used to style the action bar itself, and on that nested(?) style, `android:background` is the background used for the action bar.

What I don't know is how to craft an `?android:attr/`, to be applied to a `ListView`, that pulls the background from the action bar's defined style.

Is this possible? If so, what's the syntax?

My guess is that this is not possible, which is why the official `DrawerLayout` sample hard-codes the background color...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible unfortunately via XML.

You could do the following in code (untested, but should work):

```
// Need to manually create android.styleable.ActionBar.
// If you need other attributes, add them
int[] android_styleable_ActionBar = { android.R.attr.background };

// Need to get resource id of style pointed to from actionBarStyle
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarStyle, outValue, true);

// Now get action bar style values...
TypedArray abStyle = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(outValue.resourceId,
    android_styleable_ActionBar);
// background is the first attr in the array above so it's index is 0.
Drawable bg = abStyle.getDrawable(0);
abStyle.recycle();
```

Comment: That would require creating a custom subclass of `ListView`, to be able to access the `attrs` `AttributeSet`. Given that, I'm more inclined just to have the `ListView` point to the same resource that I set up for a custom action bar style. It's less DRY, but unless I have other reasons for a dedicated `ListView` subclass, it's still probably simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. You could even just create a custom attr in your app, set that in your theme and redirect the Action Bar and ListView styles to it.

Comment: Ah, good point. That is DRYer, even though my spell checker thinks that "DRYer" isn't a word... :-)

Comment: I've just changed my code sample above so it can be called from an Activity/Fragment. Remove's the need for a custom view class.

Comment: `android.R.styleable` isn't in the public API. Eclipse can't find it, anyway.

Comment: Damn forgot about that, fixed above (again).

Comment: That works. Of course, they renamed `setBackgroundDrawable()` to `setBackground()` in API Level 16, requiring the ever-popular check-the-build-and-pay-no-attention-to-that-deprecation-warning `if` block... :-) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT it's simply not possible to use any `?android:attr` syntax in order to address actionbar background, simply because there is no such attribute exported in the related [attrs.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml)
You should add/define such attribute in your custom theme, then use a reference in your styles/layouts. Eg:

-attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTheme">
    <attr name="actionbarBackground" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

-themes.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
    <item name="actionbarBackground">@color/your_fav_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionbar</item>
    ...
</style>
```

-styles.xml

```
...
<style name="CustomActionbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/actionbarBackground</item>
        ....
</style>
```